# find element from list and put to front, while preserving order

Tags: haskell

Im trying to make a function that takes a list of colours and a specific colour as input. It will look through the list of colours until it finds the specific colour and put it in the front. I want to do this all while perserving the order of the rest of the numbers.

So for example:

```
putfront [] (red:blue:green:yellow:white:pink:orange:[]) yellow
```

returns

```
yellow:red:blue:green:white:pink:orange:[]
```

This is my attempt:

```
putfront::[Colour]->[Colour]->Colour-> [Colour]
putfront leftofcurrent (current:rightofcurrent) thecolour
    |current==thecolour = thecolour:leftofcurrent:rightofcurrent
    |otherwise= putfront (leftofcurrent:current:[]) rightofcurrent thecolour
```

But Haskell doesn't seem to be too happy with:

```
thecolour:leftofcurrent:rightofcurrent
```

and

```
(leftofcurrent:current:[])
```

saying:

> Expected type: Pond_Ix
>         Actual type: [Pond_Ix]

What is wrong?

Comment: I know i could do it like, look at list, remove element, then add it to the front with two functions, but Id like to do it with one.

Comment: `putfront x xs = x:delete x xs`? I put this as a comment rather than an answer because, while it demonstrates an alternate approach that I strongly encourage, it does not answer the question of "what is wrong?".

Answer (score 2):

> But Haskell doesn't seem to be too happy with:
>
> ```
> thecolour:leftofcurrent:rightofcurrent
> ```

That's because `leftofcurrent` is a List. If you want to combine those lists, it needs to be:

```haskell
(thecolour:leftofcurrent) ++ rightofcurrent
```

Likewise, `(leftofcurrent:current:[])` is impossible because `leftofcurrent` is a List, but this is probably what you're after:

```haskell
leftofcurrent ++ [current]
```

The cons operator `:` expects a single element on the left and a list on the right. But because of its fixity, you can chain them together so that a bunch of single items are separated by `:` and ended with a list. That is,

```haskell
item1:item2:item3:[]
-- is the same as
item1:(item2:(item3:[]))
```

Also, your pattern matching is non-exhaustive. You need to handle the case where the second list parameter is empty.

```haskell
putfront leftofcurrent [] thecolour = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as follows

```
putfront :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
putfront a x | a `elem` x = a: filter (not . (==a)) x
             | otherwise = x

> putfront 4 [1..8]
[4,1,2,3,5,6,7,8]
```

you can recursively write it as well

```
putfront a x = bubble [] x
         where bubble p [] = p
               bubble p (s:ss) | a==s = a:p++ss
                               | otherwise = bubble (p++[s]) ss
> putfront 3 [1..5]
[3,1,2,4,5]

> putfront 7 [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that your best soln is to remove the item and put it at the front of the list, as you mention in the comment.  Given that you don't like this, may I suggest the following

```
sortBy (\x y -> case (x, y) of (_, theColour) -> GT; (x, y) ->LT) listOfColours
```

Comment: I was told that, even though not by much, it is better to do things in single functions because it takes the computer time to match higher order functions.